# Jquery Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am working on a task where I am displaying the data on the kendo grid. now I want to dynamically increase the count of records based on some conditions and append the count to some global variable. It is assigning the counts without any issues on the initial load of grid but I want to refresh the variable values too when the grid data got refreshed. below I have attached my code.

```
var completed_count = 0;
var in_progress_count = 0;
var verification_pending_count = 0;
var hr_verification_pending_count = 0;

//code for filtering
function filter(start = '', end = '', search = '', type = '', ids = ''){
        initialLoad = true;
        if(start == '' && end == ''){
            var date_range = $('.daterange-ranges').val();
            var date_range_arr = date_range.split("-");
            start = moment(date_range_arr[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            end = moment(date_range_arr[1]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        }

        if (search == '') {
            search = $('#search').val();
        }

        if (type == '') {
            type = $('#form_type').val();
        }
        
        var grid= $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        
        grid.setDataSource(grid_data_source(start,end,search,type,ids));
        grid.refresh();
        
        
    }

//initial grid load code
function load_grid(){
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            autoBind:true,
            noRecords: true,
            dataSource: grid_data_source(),
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
            pageable: true,
            detailInit: detailInit,
            pageable: {
                alwaysVisible: true,
                pageSizes: [5, 10, 15, 20, 100]
            },

            filterable:true,
            selectable: "row",
            columns: [
                { field: "name", title: "Name", filterable: false, width: 200},
                { field: "email", title: "Email", filterable: false, width: 100},
                { field: "mobile", title: "Phone", filterable: false, width: 100},
                { field: "store", title: "Store", filterable: false, width: 150},
                { field: "status", title: "Status", width: 100, filterable: false,
                    template: function(dataItem) {
                        var actions = '';
                        if (dataItem.status == 1 && dataItem.verified_status == 1 && dataItem.hr_verified_status == 1) {
                            actions += '<span style="background-color: #49e755; padding: 5px; color: #04420c; border-radius: 5px;">Completed</span>';
                            
                            completed_count = completed_count +1;
                        }
                        else if (dataItem.status == 0) {
                            actions += '<span style="background-color: #e1e38a; padding: 5px; color: #5c5a05; border-radius: 5px;">In Progress</span>';
                            in_progress_count = in_progress_count +1;
                        }
                        else if (dataItem.status == 1 && dataItem.verified_status == 0) {
                            actions += '<span style="background-color: #e1e38a; padding: 5px; color: #5c5a05; border-radius: 5px;">Verification Pending</span>';
                            verification_pending_count = verification_pending_count +1;
                        }
                        else if (dataItem.status == 1 && dataItem.verified_status == 1 && dataItem.hr_verified_status == 0) {
                            actions += '<span style="background-color: #e1e38a; padding: 5px; color: #5c5a05; border-radius: 5px;">HR Verification Pending</span>';
                            hr_verification_pending_count = hr_verification_pending_count +1;
                        }
                      return actions;
                    }
                },
                

            ],
            dataBound: function(e)
            {
                $('[data-popup="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            }
        });
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by reading the row values of grid and setting the variables.

```
function get_data(){
        var completed_count = 0;
        var in_progress_count = 0;
        var verification_pending_count = 0;
        var hr_verification_pending_count = 0;

        var entityGrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");       
        var data = entityGrid.dataSource.data();
        var totalNumber = data.length;

        for(var i = 0; i<totalNumber; i++) {
            var element = data[i];
            if (element.status == 1 && element.verified_status == 1 && element.hr_verified_status == 1) {
                        
                completed_count = completed_count +1;
            }
            else if (element.status == 0) {
                in_progress_count = in_progress_count +1;
            }
            else if (element.status == 1 && element.verified_status == 0) {
                verification_pending_count = verification_pending_count +1;
            }
            else if (element.status == 1 && data.verified_status == 1 && element.hr_verified_status == 0) {
                hr_verification_pending_count = hr_verification_pending_count +1;
            }
        }
        
        $('#completed').text(completed_count);
        $('#in_progress').text(in_progress_count);
        $('#verification').text(verification_pending_count);
        $('#hr_verification').text(hr_verification_pending_count);
        
    }
```

and I had called this method is side the data bound method of grid.